# Varible declaration

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I Want to assign the variable in the below in plpgsql.

```
declare file_name varchar;
    i_str varchar(500);
    start_date date;
 end_date date;

    select  v_file_name=concat('tmp_',replace(replace(rd.file_name,'.csv',''),'-','_'))  as files  
            ,rd.filter_2 = i_str
    from reports as rd 
    where rd.id = rep_id 
          and rd.status=0;

    if ( file_name) is not null
    begin

    update report_downloads set status=1 where id =rep_id and status=0

    end;
else 
    begin
    update report_downloads  set status=3 where id =rep_id and status=1
    end;
```

But could see below issue:

CONTEXT: invalid type
SQL state: 42601 
Character: 202

Comment: you are missing a `begin` before your `select` to end the [declare section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) (and the corresponding `end;`). An `if` [requires a `then`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) and is ended with an `end if;`

Comment: ```select  v_file_name=concat('tmp_',replace(replace(rd.file_name,'.csv',''),'-','_'))  as files  
            ,rd.filter_2 = i_str
    from reports as rd 
    where rd.id = rep_id 
          and rd.status=0; ``` is the varible assigned correctly

Comment: Assigning variables is not done that in way in PL/pgSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Comment: ```declare v_file_name character varying(100);
 i_str varchar(500);
 start_date date;
 end_date date;
 
 select  file_name INTO  v_file_name
         ,filter_2 into i_str
 from reports``` tried this and got ```ERROR: syntax error at or near "," LINE 3: ,filter_2 into i_str ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 117``` ERROR

Comment: The INTO isn't repeated.

Comment: It is repeated and same issue

Comment: You should **not** repeat the INTO, `select a,b,c into v_a, v_b, v_c from ...`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still stuck on this matter:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   -- assign your variables here
   -- [variable_name] [type];
BEGIN
   -- do some code
   -- SELECT 1 INTO [variable] FROM ...
   -- [variable] := [value]
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hope this helps